# Spring: xsi:schemaLocation can't read configuration from spring.schemas

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, spring, xsd

I have a personnal namespace I want to use in my applicationContext.xml. 
I am using Spring3.

So, in my appliationContext, in beans tag I have :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
xmlns:profile="http://icfi.com/springbeans/profile"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd 
    http://icfi.com/springbeans/profile http://icfi.com/springbeans/profile/profile.xsd">
```

The important line here is

`http://icfi.com/springbeans/profile http://icfi.com/springbeans/profile/profile.xsd`

I say that I want to use the profile.xsd. Obviously, this file is not online, but I have a spring.schemas file in my META-INF folder with :

```
http\://icfi.com/springbeans/profile/profile.xsd=profile.xsd
```

in it.

My local profile.xsd file is in src/main/resources.

My problem is that in eclipse, it says it can't find the xsd. Si I give him the absolute path to my file :

`file:///c:/[...]/project/src/main/resources/profile.xsd`

The problem is the same
Then I give him only "profile.xsd" and the full line become :

`http://icfi.com/springbeans/profile profile.xsd`

And here Eclipse can read it ! hurray ? Not really because : 
It didn't read my spring.schemas since I have to give the real (relative) path to my file, and more important, when I start my application, in every case (with the url from spring.schema, with the full path or relative path) I always have :

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'profile.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:?]
```

I think my profile.xsd is good because I can make eclipse to read it, but just in case, here is my file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://icfi.com/springbeans/profile"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
targetNamespace="http://icfi.com/springbeans/profile"
elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xsd:element name="if">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:any minOccurs="0" />
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="test" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
        <xsd:attribute name="src" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

I really can't figure out why :

- I can't bind "http://icfi.com/springbeans/profile/profile.xsd" to my profile.xsd
- I can't read the profile.xsd even if eclipses says it can read it and it's okay.

Can you help me to find a solution please ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I export my namespaceHadler and parser to an external jar, and it works fine. 
For the binding, I have uploaded the xsd online.

Now it works fine :)